# why file in gitignore will be modified after android studio compile?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-stage

I have a file called VersionUtil and set it into the gitignore.
In the gitignore file, I have

```
# Git info
app/src/main/java/com/test/util/VersionUtil.java
```

Before I run the project in android studio, there's a line of code in VersionUtil.java:

```
public static final String COMMIT_INFO = "info".
```

I ran  git status and it returned

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
```

However, after I run the project, VersionUtil.java was changed. That line is:

```
public static final String COMMIT_INFO = "6a604 XXXXX ".
```

The git status returned

```
modified:   app/src/main/java/com/test/util/VersionUtil.java
```

Do you guys have any idea? Why the file in gitignore is still being tracked? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I took the liberty of removing the `github-api` tag and adding the `git` tag, since this question does not have any connection to GitHub or its API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `.gitignore` file affects only *untracked* files. Files that are already *tracked* are not affected in any way by a `.gitignore` file. This means that if a file is already under version control and then added to the `.gitignore` *later*, Git will not start ignoring the already-tracked file then.

To quote the man page (emphasis mine):

> A gitignore file specifies **intentionally untracked** files that Git should ignore. **Files already tracked by Git are not affected** [...].
>
> [...]
>
> - The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files **not tracked by Git remain untracked**.
> - To ignore **uncommitted changes in a file that is already tracked**, use `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.
> - To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git `rm --cached`.

The second suggested alternative might be the way to go for you:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged app/src/main/java/com/test/util/VersionUtil.java
```

Alternatively, you can remove the file (either physically, or from version control only). After that, the `.gitignore` file should be effective:

```
git rm --cached app/src/main/java/com/test/util/VersionUtil.java
git commit -m'Remove VersionUtil.java from version control'
```

Comment: Hi Helmbert, Thanks for your answer. Does that mean if a file is already pushed to github, the gitignore will not affect it at all?

Comment: Basically correct. Having been pushed (to Github, or whereever) is not the crucial point however. A file is *tracked* as soon as it has been added to a  commit (remember, commits are local in Git!). If you feel like reading up on the different states a file can have in a Git repository, I can recommend [this chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) from the *Pro Git* book.